# Device Tree for PHY-less connection to a DSA switch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ethernet, device-tree

We have a little problem with creating a device tree for our configuration of a Marvell DSA switch and a Xilinx Zynq processor. They are connected like this:

```
|——————————————|               |——————————————————————————————|
|     e000b000—|———— SGMII ————|—port6 (0x16)      port3 —— PHY3
| Zynq         |               |         mv88e6321            |
|     e000c000—|—x           x—|—port5             port4 —— PHY4
|——————————————|               |——————————————————————————————|
        |___________ MDIO _______________|
```

And we have a device tree for the Linux kernel, which looks like this:

```
ps7_ethernet_0: ps7-ethernet@e000b000 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
            clocks = <&clkc 13>, <&clkc 30>;
            compatible = "xlnx,ps7-ethernet-1.00.a";
            interrupt-parent = <&ps7_scugic_0>;
            interrupts = <0 22 4>;
            local-mac-address = [00 0a 35 00 00 00];
            phy-handle = <&phy0>;
            phy-mode = "gmii";
            reg = <0xe000b000 0x1000>;
            xlnx,ptp-enet-clock = <0x69f6bcb>;
            xlnx,enet-reset = "";
            xlnx,eth-mode = <0x0>;
            xlnx,has-mdio = <0x1>;
            mdio_0: mdio {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                phy0: phy@16 {
                    compatiable = "marvell,dsa";
                    reg = <0x16>;
                } ;
            } ;

} ;

    dsa@0 {
            compatible = "marvell,dsa";

            #address-cells = <2>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            interrupts = <10>;

            dsa,ethernet = <&ps7_ethernet_0>;
            dsa,mii-bus = <&mdio_0>;

            switch@0 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                reg = <0 0>;
             port@3 {
                    reg = <3>;
                    label = "lan0";                
             };
             port@4 {
                    reg = <4>;
                    label = "lan1";
             };
             port@5 {
                    reg = <5>;
                    label = "lan2";
             };
             port@6 {
                    reg = <6>;
                    label = "cpu";       
             };
        };
        };     
} ;
```

The problem is, as you can see from the picture, there is no PHY attached to the port 6, i.e. the connection between the Zynq and the switch is PHY-less, but I had to specify `<phy0>` in the device tree to make the dsa driver to see the switch. But then it tries to talk to a non-existent PHY and fails, obviously.

So the question is: how to create a proper device tree for a dsa switch connected to a processor like this?

Thank you for any help!

(There is a somewhat similar question [P1010 MAC to Switch port direct connection without PHY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034159/p1010-mac-to-switch-port-direct-connection-without-phy) but I cannot comment on it and there is no answer, unfortunately)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of specifying &phy0 when there is none, you can write it as fixed-link

fixed-link = <0 1 1000 0 0>;

Where 0 is emulated PHY ID, 1-> full-duplex and speed is 1000 Mb/s.
You would also want to disable autonegotiation for the processor port to which switch port 6 is connected.

```
ps7_ethernet_0: ps7-ethernet@e000b000 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
        clocks = <&clkc 13>, <&clkc 30>;
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-ethernet-1.00.a";
        interrupt-parent = <&ps7_scugic_0>;
        interrupts = <0 22 4>;
        local-mac-address = [00 0a 35 00 00 00];
        fixed-link = <0 1 1000 0 0>;
        phy-mode = "gmii";
        reg = <0xe000b000 0x1000>;
        xlnx,ptp-enet-clock = <0x69f6bcb>;
        xlnx,enet-reset = "";
        xlnx,eth-mode = <0x0>;
        xlnx,has-mdio = <0x1>;
        mdio_0: mdio {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
        } ;
```

} ;

```
dsa@0 {
        compatible = "marvell,dsa";

        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        interrupts = <10>;

        dsa,ethernet = <&ps7_ethernet_0>;
        dsa,mii-bus = <&mdio_0>;

        switch@0 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <22 0>;
         port@3 {
                reg = <3>;
                label = "lan0";                
         };
         port@4 {
                reg = <4>;
                label = "lan1";
         };
         port@5 {
                reg = <5>;
                label = "lan2";
         };
         port@6 {
                reg = <6>;
                label = "cpu";       
         };
    };
    };
```

} ;

I'm assuming switch chip SMI address is 0x16; if not make reg = <22,0> to <0,0> as before under switch@0.
Also you may need to add mdio driver reg address and compatible property , which are not specified in your device tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do I specify which port address the processor is connected to? I'm having
dsa: probe of dsa@22 failed with error -22

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of a device tree with such a property?

Comment: Since there is no external PHY chip as Switch is connected directly to processor MII bus, there is no need to specify phy0: phy@16 {..} under mdio_0: mdio. Remove phy part from mdio
Also if there is no external phy, how can you specify phy reg address as 0x16 for phy on mdio. 
Is 0x16 SMI address of Switch chip ? If yes, then it need to be specified under switch@0 as reg = <22 0> or reg = <0x16 0>;